# How to remove from django sitemap pagination ?p=(1,2,3...n)

Tags: django, sitemap, django-sitemaps

Okay we have a lot of pages. So when the content pages spill over 400 is created next page for sitemap and it looks like that - sitemap-instructions.xml?p=5

The problem is that pagination is conflicted with robots.txt where we have restrictions for many things including pagination pages.

So we tried to handle it with robots.txt but got more problems than we had.

My question is How to edit pagination address and replace or remove ?p=